# Ruby wrapper for libjpeg to resize image

Tags: ruby, resize, wrapper, libjpeg, rhomobile

is there a ruby wrapper for the libjpeg library (http://www.ijg.org/)? What I'm trying to do is create an extension to the Rhomobile Framework so that I can resize images on my mobile app.

Thanks,

Nick,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution might be to offload this work to an external service if possible.

I did find this though:  [jpegtran ruby gem](https://github.com/martinkozak/jpegtran)  jpegtran can be used to resize via libjpeg, if available on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it will suit your needs for mobile, but give rmagick a spin

Comment: rmagick is definitely not available on the platform.  I am taking the user's word that libjpeg is available.